# How does the use of slang words / language among young people affect their relationship with older generation?

Tags: sociolinguistics

I'm doing a research for my sociolinguistics class. Do you think this is a good topic?

Comment: I expect you mean new slang, the kind that the previous generation isn't familiar with. It gives each new generation a flattering sense of being in the know while viewing everyone else as a sucker, the way any specialized slang used by any group of people allows the members of that group to feel superior to everyone who isn't initiated: a trait common among members of street gangs, members of academia, pilots, cops, actors, etc.